# The origin of "отморозок"

Tags: этимология

Отморозок is a contemptible and objectionable person.

It looks like the word comes from the verb отморозить, or the noun мороз.

Why is отморозок originally associated with getting frostbite, freezing or just frost?

Comment: Can be connected with _мерзавец_ (scoundrel) and _мерзкий_ (detestable, filthy) through _мёрзнуть_ (to suffer from cold, to freeze), have a look here, [“Мерзавец” — откуда взялось ругательство](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/19500/180619) at Русский язык SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.

My first guess was that since Russia is a very cold country, Russians figuratively referred to scumbags as to people whose brain got damaged by frost, hence **отморозок**. My guess was based on the existence of the similar word **отмороженный** (literally "damaged by frost"), which refers to a scumbag, too. The idea is that once your brain gets damaged by frost, you become capable of doing terrible things that normal people are uncapable of doing.

Then I tried to google the etymology of **отморозок** and found numerous theories, including a [theory](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5b6aa2a528eb1300ac9ab365/otkuda-proizoshlo-slovo-otmorozok-5b98ea1dc9e72b00a91dc4c9) that this word  originally denoted a young wolf excluded from its pack:

> Поэтому таких молодых волков, которые своими поступками ставили под угрозу жизнь волчьего общества, из стаи выгоняли. Так как дело происходило по первому снегу и морозу, такого волка звали «отморозок». То есть это молодой волк, совершивший плохой поступок, и за это изгнанный из волчьего общества.

An [article](https://russian7.ru/post/kogo-na-rusi-nazyvali-otmorozkami/) on the portal *Русская семерка* claims that the word originates from criminal slang of the 19th century:

> Слово изначально употреблялось в воровском жаргоне XIX века. Оно означает оборванца, отброса общества, представителя маргинальной молодежи, который не знает настоящих воровских законов, но при этом совершает противоправные действия.

Another [theory](https://commerage.ru/znachenie-familii/moroz) says that this word denoted a runaway serf:

> От «чёрных» крестьян. Которые не бежали на юг в казачество. А как правило уходили в леса или на болота (никого не боясь, готовые постоять за себя). Из-за этого их стали называть отморозками. Места их проживания Морозами (д. Морозы; Нижние Морозы; Верхние Морозы — Беларусь, Украина), а затем уже сопоставили и фамилию Мороз.

I also found explanations sounding similar to my hypothesis:

> Отморозок = отмороженный = ничего не понимающий, не отдающий отчёта в происходящем… Попробуйте помёрзнуть в на ветру в – 30-40 градусов… потом, когда совсем замёрзнете – и вас принесут домой… попытайтесь мыслить логически – поймёте…) ([Source](https://trueinform.ru/modules.php?name=Video&file=print&sid=193345))
>
> Мне всегда казалось, что отморозок – это тот, у кого мозги отморожены. И появилось это понятие от болезни под названием менингит – воспаления мозга, его рискуют получить люди, которые ходят в мороз без шапки. Одним из последствий менингита является задержка умственного развития. (Same source as above)
>
> Отморозок - агрессор без правил, как будто с отмороженными мозгами. ([Source](http://www.polukhin.com/node/142))

To find out which theory is true, I looked in dictionaries, but was unable to find any dictionary that provides the etymology of this word. In particular, neither the etymological dictionary by Preobrazhensky nor the etymological dictionary by Vasmer contain this word. Vladimir Dal's famous explanatory dictionary does not contain the word either.

In Google Books and in the Russian National Corpus this word can be found only starting from the 1990s, and there are no hits in Google Books and Russian National Corpus for **отморозокъ**, the spelling in accordance with the old spelling rules. This undermines theories in which the word has an old origin.

I looked in Google Books to see how the word **отморозилъ** (i.e., in the old spelling) was used, and in all instances it meant "damaged by frost."

Interestingly, I found numerous examples in Google of use of the word **обморозок** (i.e., with **б** instead of **т**), which seems to have the same meaning as **отморозок**, e.g.:

> В Архангельской области обморозок зарезал пенсионерку, чтобы забрать водку и 200 рублей. ([Source](https://xn--m1ahc.xn--80asehdb/novosti/arhangelsk/v-arhangelskoi-oblasti-obmorozok-zarezal-pensionerku-chtoby-zabrat-vodku-i-200-rublei.html))
>
> – А этот, раненный, кто? – Да никто. Обморозок местный. Его опера как облупленного знают. Бандит с примесью «баклана». (From [book](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/27043/Kivinov_12_Polnoe_blyudce_sekretov.html) "Полное блюдце секретов" by Kivinov)

Like **отморозить**, the word **обморозить** means "to damage by frost," so the concurrent use of **обморозок** and  **отморозок** supports my original hypothesis.

Another fact supporting my original hypothesis is that the word **отморозок** is sometimes used to refer to slow thinkers:

> Отморозок: идиот, тугодум. Частая характеристика конченного, окончательно опустившегося наркомана. ([Source](http://endic.ru/drugslang/Otmorozok-207.html))

This is concurrent with my hypothesis, because slow thinkers can be figuratively compared with people whose brain got damaged by frost. Other theories do not explain how **отморозок** could come to mean a slow thinker.

To conclude, we may never know the true etymology of **отморозок**, but, given the evidence at hand, I'd say that my first guess may well be the truth.

Comment: This one is not right at least partially: "а затем уже сопоставили и фамилию Мороз." - Мороз was a Slavic name.

Comment: @shabunc : Yes, I dislike the theories I quoted, and I like my hypothesis more.

Comment: "обморозок" is most probably a typo.

Comment: Actually, does not look like a typo if you read the google results.. but I've never heard/seen it before and couldn't grasp the difference from "отморозок" so far (if there is any). Might be something regional(?)

Comment: @tum_ : If it is a typo, then it is a very frequent typo :) Also, the keys Б and Т are not adjacent :)

Comment: @Mitsuko it's 99.9% a typo - and the reason is that Б is  next to T on Russian Keyboard.

Comment: @shabunc : isn't the key Ь between the keys Т and Б?

Comment: @shabunc : If it is a typo, why are there so many Google results for обморозок? https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA Are they all typos?

Comment: @Mitsuko it is however they are still close, google found about 1 thousand usages from which main are about "обморозок" in a different meaning, However I do not insist  - language and it's usage is bigger than any personal experience.

Comment: "Результатов: примерно 1 440" - this is not many, this is very few (you keep underestimating the amount of text being generated on the Net every minute).   And these 1440 are indeed a mixture of typos, some ad-hoc usages related to 'frost', the equivalents of "отморозок" that some people somehow decided to use instead and some different meaning of "обморозок" that I struggle to figure out (and, given the scale, will not waste my time on this any more).  When you get to the last page it becomes "Page 14 of about 138 results" - the rest are duplicates.

Comment: @tum_ : I found the word **обморозок** even in books. For example, just google the exact phrase "обморозок местный", and you will see the book. It is surely not a typo, for it is a book. And the meaning is clearly the same as that of **отморозок**.

Comment: @shabunc : No worries. The Russian language is so rich lexically that even native speakers cannot fully master it.

Comment: I wouldn't put much trust in a source which has something like `в нашей истории очень многое намеренно забыто, переписано и перековеркано, мы не знаем исходные смыслы слов, которыми пользуемся` (your first link).

Comment: @Headcrab : I didn't put much trust in that source. I like my own hypothesis more.

Comment: Hmm. I think it is actually from criminal slang. Russians know that a part of the body damaged by frost changes its color (becomes white) and stops being felt, so it becomes like a foreign part in the body. So, criminals that parted with the major gangs, are like those foreign parts of the criminal world.

Comment: I suppose it's because they have a frozen brain. :)
"Мне всегда казалось, что отморозок – это тот, у кого мозги отморожены. " - it's really right, and the transparent methaphore without any labyrinthined speculations-hypotheses... It should be added - this is a slang, and it has appeared in real сommon and wide using recently only - since Perestroika only :> As it's obvious, these отморозки themselfes too

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed derived from the adjective «отмороженный», which means someone who has no moral and no sentiments of any kind (like his emotions were frozen). This word in this particular meaning initially came from criminal jargon.

«Мерзавец» and «мразь» mentioned in a comment have indeed the same etymology and are connected to «мороз».

Сonnotation of lack of emotions is something quite common for frost-related words is not something uncommon to Russian, check out, for instance "холодно посмотреть", "холодная жестокость", "холодный расчёт".

As a side note, there’s also a verb «отморозиться» which ironically has nothing to do with «отморозок» or «отмороженный». «Отморозиться» means to ignore someone’s invitation or request.